# Rearranging Legend ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

First off, thank you for any input. I am relatively new to R so any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated. So I have the following graph: 
[image]

I would like to rearrange the legend so it would look something like this so it is a little easier to understand:
[image]

I tried using `scale_fill_discrete` to no avial. Here is my code:

```
carb_data<- read.csv("Carb_Insulin_BG.csv", header=TRUE)



library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#get data for patient 1
data1<-subset(carb_data,Subject.ID.. == 1)

#get all the data from Visit 1
carb1<-subset(data1,Visit == 1)

visit1 <- toString(carb1[1,3])

carb1<- mutate(carb1, Start=sprintf("%05s", as.character(Start)), Amount= as.numeric(as.character(Amount)))

q <- ggplot(data=carb1, aes(x=Start, y=Amount, group=Description, color= Description, shape=Type, label=Amount )) + geom_text(data=carb1[carb1$Type=="Insulin (units)", ], size=3, hjust=0, vjust=2, color="black") + geom_bar(data=carb1[carb1$Type=="Carb (grams)", ], stat="identity", width=.1) + geom_point(size=2) + theme(text = element_text(size=10), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, max(carb1$Amount), by = 50),2)) + xlab("Time (HH:MM)") + ylab("Value") + ggtitle(toString(c("Carbohydrate, Insulin ,and Blood Glucose Data \n Site ID 1 \nVisit", visit1)))

q
```

And my data:

```
> dput(carb1)
structure(list(EDC.ID. = structure(c(34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 14L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 14L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 14L, 34L, 
34L, 14L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("Subject 1", "Subject 10", "Subject 11", 
"Subject 12", "Subject 13", "Subject 14", "Subject 15", "Subject 16", 
"Subject 17", "Subject 18", "Subject 19", "Subject 2", "Subject 20", 
"Subject 3", "Subject 4", "Subject 5", "Subject 6", "Subject 7", 
"Subject 8", "Subject 9", "SUBJECT1", "SUBJECT10", "SUBJECT11", 
"SUBJECT12", "SUBJECT13", "SUBJECT14", "SUBJECT15", "SUBJECT16", 
"SUBJECT17", "SUBJECT18", "SUBJECT19", "SUBJECT2", "SUBJECT20", 
"SUBJECT3", "SUBJECT4", "SUBJECT5", "SUBJECT6", "SUBJECT7", "SUBJECT8", 
"SUBJECT9"), class = "factor"), Subject.ID.. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Visit = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Data = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
12L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-", "10/1/14", "10/3/14", 
"10/7/14", "8/14/14", "8/18/14", "8/19/14", "8/20/14", "8/21/14", 
"8/25/14", "8/27/14", "8/28/14", "9/1/14", "9/10/14", "9/12/14", 
"9/15/14", "9/16/14", "9/18/14", "9/19/14", "9/2/14", "9/22/14", 
"9/23/14", "9/24/14", "9/25/14", "9/26/14", "9/29/14", "9/3/14", 
"9/30/14", "9/4/14", "9/5/14", "9/8/14", "9/9/14"), class = "factor"), 
    Start = c("00:00", "09:02", "09:25", "09:55", "10:10", "11:00", 
    "11:15", "11:49", "11:54", "12:04", "13:05", "13:25", "13:40", 
    "14:40", "15:10", "15:40", "16:10", "16:10", "16:40", "17:10", 
    "17:10", "17:40"), End = structure(c(1L, 483L, 504L, 530L, 
    14L, 62L, 75L, 108L, 113L, 122L, 181L, 201L, 238L, 270L, 
    298L, 327L, 357L, 357L, 387L, 416L, 416L, 439L), .Label = c("0:00", 
    "0:16", "1:25", "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03", "10:04", 
    "10:05", "10:06", "10:07", "10:08", "10:09", "10:10", "10:11", 
    "10:12", "10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "10:16", "10:17", "10:18", 
    "10:19", "10:20", "10:21", "10:22", "10:23", "10:24", "10:25", 
    "10:27", "10:28", "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", "10:32", "10:33", 
    "10:34", "10:35", "10:36", "10:37", "10:38", "10:39", "10:40", 
    "10:41", "10:42", "10:43", "10:44", "10:45", "10:46", "10:47", 
    "10:48", "10:49", "10:50", "10:51", "10:52", "10:53", "10:54", 
    "10:55", "10:57", "10:58", "10:59", "11:00", "11:01", "11:03", 
    "11:04", "11:05", "11:06", "11:07", "11:08", "11:09", "11:10", 
    "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", "11:16", "11:17", "11:18", 
    "11:19", "11:20", "11:21", "11:22", "11:23", "11:24", "11:25", 
    "11:26", "11:27", "11:28", "11:29", "11:30", "11:31", "11:33", 
    "11:34", "11:35", "11:36", "11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", 
    "11:41", "11:42", "11:43", "11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", 
    "11:48", "11:49", "11:50", "11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", 
    "11:55", "11:56", "11:57", "11:58", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", 
    "12:03", "12:04", "12:05", "12:06", "12:07", "12:08", "12:09", 
    "12:10", "12:11", "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "12:16", 
    "12:18", "12:19", "12:20", "12:21", "12:22", "12:23", "12:24", 
    "12:25", "12:26", "12:27", "12:28", "12:29", "12:30", "12:31", 
    "12:32", "12:33", "12:34", "12:35", "12:36", "12:37", "12:38", 
    "12:39", "12:40", "12:41", "12:42", "12:43", "12:44", "12:45", 
    "12:46", "12:47", "12:48", "12:49", "12:50", "12:51", "12:52", 
    "12:53", "12:54", "12:55", "12:56", "12:57", "12:58", "12:59", 
    "13:00", "13:01", "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:07", 
    "13:08", "13:09", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", 
    "13:15", "13:16", "13:17", "13:18", "13:19", "13:20", "13:21", 
    "13:22", "13:23", "13:24", "13:25", "13:27", "13:28", "13:29", 
    "13:30", "13:31", "13:32", "13:33", "13:34", "13:35", "13:36", 
    "13:37", "13:38", "13:39", "13:40", "13:41", "13:42", "13:44", 
    "13:45", "13:46", "13:48", "13:49", "13:50", "13:51", "13:52", 
    "13:53", "13:54", "13:55", "13:56", "13:57", "13:58", "13:59", 
    "14:00", "14:01", "14:02", "14:03", "14:04", "14:05", "14:06", 
    "14:08", "14:09", "14:10", "14:11", "14:12", "14:14", "14:15", 
    "14:16", "14:17", "14:18", "14:19", "14:20", "14:21", "14:22", 
    "14:23", "14:24", "14:25", "14:26", "14:27", "14:28", "14:29", 
    "14:30", "14:31", "14:33", "14:34", "14:35", "14:36", "14:37", 
    "14:38", "14:39", "14:40", "14:41", "14:42", "14:43", "14:44", 
    "14:45", "14:46", "14:48", "14:49", "14:50", "14:51", "14:52", 
    "14:53", "14:54", "14:55", "14:57", "14:58", "14:59", "15:00", 
    "15:01", "15:02", "15:03", "15:04", "15:05", "15:06", "15:07", 
    "15:08", "15:09", "15:10", "15:12", "15:13", "15:14", "15:15", 
    "15:16", "15:17", "15:18", "15:19", "15:20", "15:21", "15:22", 
    "15:23", "15:24", "15:25", "15:26", "15:27", "15:28", "15:29", 
    "15:30", "15:31", "15:32", "15:33", "15:34", "15:35", "15:36", 
    "15:37", "15:38", "15:39", "15:40", "15:41", "15:42", "15:43", 
    "15:44", "15:45", "15:46", "15:47", "15:48", "15:49", "15:50", 
    "15:51", "15:52", "15:53", "15:54", "15:55", "15:56", "15:57", 
    "15:58", "15:59", "16:00", "16:01", "16:02", "16:03", "16:04", 
    "16:05", "16:06", "16:07", "16:08", "16:09", "16:10", "16:11", 
    "16:12", "16:13", "16:14", "16:15", "16:16", "16:17", "16:18", 
    "16:19", "16:20", "16:21", "16:22", "16:23", "16:24", "16:25", 
    "16:26", "16:27", "16:28", "16:29", "16:30", "16:31", "16:32", 
    "16:33", "16:34", "16:35", "16:36", "16:37", "16:38", "16:39", 
    "16:40", "16:42", "16:43", "16:44", "16:45", "16:46", "16:47", 
    "16:48", "16:49", "16:50", "16:51", "16:52", "16:53", "16:54", 
    "16:55", "16:56", "16:57", "16:58", "16:59", "17:00", "17:01", 
    "17:02", "17:03", "17:04", "17:05", "17:06", "17:07", "17:08", 
    "17:09", "17:10", "17:11", "17:12", "17:14", "17:15", "17:17", 
    "17:18", "17:19", "17:20", "17:21", "17:22", "17:23", "17:24", 
    "17:25", "17:26", "17:29", "17:30", "17:32", "17:34", "17:35", 
    "17:36", "17:38", "17:39", "17:40", "17:45", "17:50", "17:51", 
    "17:54", "18:00", "18:09", "18:15", "2:40", "21:24", "21:27", 
    "21:39", "3:48", "7:51", "8:00", "8:04", "8:05", "8:10", 
    "8:14", "8:15", "8:18", "8:26", "8:29", "8:31", "8:33", "8:37", 
    "8:39", "8:40", "8:41", "8:43", "8:44", "8:45", "8:47", "8:48", 
    "8:50", "8:51", "8:52", "8:54", "8:55", "8:57", "8:58", "8:59", 
    "9:00", "9:01", "9:02", "9:03", "9:04", "9:05", "9:06", "9:07", 
    "9:08", "9:09", "9:11", "9:12", "9:13", "9:14", "9:15", "9:17", 
    "9:18", "9:19", "9:20", "9:21", "9:22", "9:23", "9:24", "9:25", 
    "9:27", "9:28", "9:30", "9:32", "9:33", "9:34", "9:35", "9:36", 
    "9:37", "9:38", "9:39", "9:40", "9:42", "9:43", "9:44", "9:45", 
    "9:46", "9:47", "9:48", "9:49", "9:50", "9:51", "9:52", "9:53", 
    "9:54", "9:55", "9:56", "9:57", "9:58", "9:59"), class = "factor"), 
    Description = structure(c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("BGM", "Dextrose 50% (mL)", "dextrose Tabs", 
    "Food or Drink", "Humalog (units)", "Humalog sc (units)", 
    "Humalog SC (units)", "Injection (ccs)", "IV Dextrose(mL)", 
    "Lantus (units)", "Levemir (units)", "Novolin R (units)", 
    "Novolin R IV (units)", "Oral", "Other", "YSI"), class = "factor"), 
    Amount = c(150, 161.5, 150.5, 144.5, 138, 122, 119, 114.5, 
    8, 110, 57.95, 53.95, 127, 102, 156, 217, 8, 250, 273, 4, 
    275, 277), Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("BG Data (mg/dL)", "Carb (grams)", "Insulin (units)"
    ), class = "factor"), Order = c(463L, 461L, 462L, 464L, 465L, 
    466L, 467L, 468L, 125L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 1L, 472L, 473L, 
    474L, 126L, 475L, 476L, 127L, 477L, 478L)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("EDC.ID.", 
"Subject.ID..", "Visit", "Data", "Start", "End", "Description", 
"Amount", "Type", "Order"), row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Comment: How far are you willing to go to do that? ggplot legends will not do that by default. You're going to have to write some pretty low-level grob manipulation code to make that happen. Do you need it to be generalizable or only work for this particular plot?

Comment: thanks for the reply @MrFlick! It would need to generalized since each patient was administered different types of Insulin and carbohydrates.

Comment: I would prefere WYSIWYG for such fiddly things, e.g. export it to an vector format and edit it by hand (`ReporteRs`for PowerPoint, `cairo`for svg (Inkscape, ...))